# Is there any way to configure opencv globally?

Tags: opencv, project-settings

*I configured opencv to a c++ project in visual basic 2012.* 
Now i want to create a another project.

*Should i have to configure opencv to it also?* *Is there any global way to configure it for all project?..*

Please help..Thanks in advance.

Comment: Use visual studio? If yes, use [Property Sheets](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/a4xbdz1e(v=vs.90).aspx).

Answer (score 0):

what I would do is to create an empty project (or with bare minimum main function) with proper OpenCV settings applied, and save the directory containing this project as a template project.  When the new project is needed, I would copy that directory, rename it, and start using it.